# Display uniform dates on x-axis in chart js in angular

Tags: css, angular, chart.js

I am displaying  line chart using chart js in angular. In x-axis I am showing date which is dynamic which is coming from api. I tried *"type:'linear'"* but still it is not working.
I want that dates which I am displaying should be uniform.

*my component.html*

```
<canvas id="myChart"></chart>
```

*my component.ts file*

```
ngOnInit(){
this.chart = document.getElementById('myChart')
this.loadchart();
}

loadchart(){
  new Chart(this.chart, {

    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: this.carArray,
            label: 'No. of car',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            fill:true
        },
      {
        data: this.priceArray,
        label: 'price',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        fill:true
      }],
      labels: this.dateArray,
    },

    options: {
       elements:{
         point: {
           radius:1
         },
       },
       plugins: {
         legend: {
           display:true
         }
       },
       responsive: true,
       scales: {
         y: {
           grid: {
             borderDash:[1,2],
           },
           brginAtZero: true
         },
         x: {
           ticks:{
             color: 'blue'
           },
          grid: {
            tickColor: 'red',
            borderDash:[1,2],
          },
          brginAtZero: true
        }
       }
    }
})
}
```

I want to display uniform dates on x axis.
[image: dates on x-axis is not uniform]

Comment: What do you mean by uniform dates? Could you maybe show an image of it or explain it better?

Comment: uniform dates means the difference between 2 dates on x axis must be same.